# easy way of setting values to wxTextCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, sudoku

I have a vector of length 81 and and 81 wxTextCtrl's...is there an easier way of displaying the values from the vector into the textCtrl's without manual typing them one bye one. i have a pointer pointing to the 1st txtCtrl. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do a batch set as you are trying to do. However, you could have a loop and then set then call [SetValue](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_entry.html#a90f876b2dd83ba5c97ba0c193b386e9f).

It would be something along the lines of

```
for(int i = 0; i < 81; ++i)
    textCtrls[i]->SetValue(values[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// vector of strings
std::vector< wxString > value;

// vector of textctrl pointers
std::vector< wxTextCtrl* > control;

// iterartors
std::vector< wxString >::iterator value_iter;
std::vector< wxTextCtrl* >::iterator control_iter;

// loop
for( value_iter = value.begin(), control_iter = control.begin();
    value_iter != value.end(); value_iter++, control_iter++ )
{
    (*control_iter)->SetValue( *value_iter );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a loop....

Comment: first idea i had...'code'for(int i = 1; i <=81;i++){string temp="TextCtrl"+i;temp->setValue(evil[i-1];);}'code'? d'dnt work